# Dim ts As New TimeSpan(Integer.Parse(timer_arr(0)), Integer.Parse(timer_arr(1)), Integer.Parse(timer_arr(2)))

Tags: html, asp.net, countdowntimer

```
Dim ts As New TimeSpan(Integer.Parse(timer_arr(0)), 
Integer.Parse(timer_arr(1)), Integer.Parse(timer_arr(2)))
```

Input string is not in correct format. What's wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output

Comment: Please modify your question title to better represent the problem that you are trying to solve. It will also be helpful if you define the contents of `timer_arr` and provide a complete example of code that others can use to replicate your issue.